# User in good standing removed -- significant reputation loss in low-traffic tag

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, voting, users

Today [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1812457/boris) of [about 4.5 years with 10K+ rep](http://web.archive.org/web/20161128064555/http://stackoverflow.com/users/1812457/boris) and [one of the longtime top](http://web.archive.org/web/20151020012247/http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/topusers) [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog) contributors has suddenly disappeared, and all his votes were *retracted*. I see sudden drop in reputation / votes for other Prolog contributors as well, for some much more massive than mine (if memory serves).

This can't be right, *right*? I thought, when a high-rep user is removed, their votes are supposed to stay.

I don't care about the rep much, but losing my recently acquired<sup>*</sup>  silver Prolog badge does not make me particularly happy today.

*edit:* apparently what matters is the impact of the votes removal. For a low-traffic tag the votes are much harder to get, so the *relative* impact of removal of the same *absolute* number of votes is much higher, than in the higher-traffic tags.

*Perhaps it's the relative impact of votes removal that should be considered in deciding whether the vote retention is warranted or not, in such cases.*

---

<sup>*</sup> (and lost, and reacquired again, a few times because of *newbie* users being removed...)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The user requested deletion, and their account did not meet the criteria for vote retention (where their votes are not automatically removed with the account). Since tag badges are directly connected with your score, that means you unfortunately lost them with the votes that user cast. Gain 13 votes and you'll have it again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the reply. Are you saying 10K+ and being in a top 5 of a tag is not sufficient for vote retention? The question *is*, this can't be right, *right*?

Comment: I don't know what the criteria are, exactly. I've poked the CM that completed the deletion process.

Comment: using the same numbers for high- and low-traffic tags can't be right.

Comment: That said, their account reputation and post history should not matter all that much, it is the impact of their voting history that matters.

Comment: Who said anything about tag popularity here? Again, it is their *outgoing votes* that matter. You and I can't see their vote history, so I certainly can't judge what their impact was.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, user lurker had about 960 in Prolog tag IIRC, now they have 890. That's a big impact.

Comment: @MartijnPieters re popularity, votes in low traffic tags are much harder to get, so their value (impact of loosing) is much higher, is what I meant.

Comment: of course, a top 10 Java tag contributor loosing measly 70 upvotes is nothing. not so in Prolog. (is what I meant).

Comment: Loosing 70 upvotes is never measly, when a long-standing account is removed (i.e. not one used to defraud the system). Regardless of what tags they were active in.

Comment: If the fact that it's in a low-traffic title is relevant to your argument, I'd suggest amending the title: "User in good standing - reputation lost in low-traffic tag"

Comment: Wow, that was massive vote destruction.  Your loss is relatively mild, a user like @capellic lost over 2000 rep.  Invalidating votes makes sense if the account was destroyed for fraud, it makes no sense whatsoever in this case.  Beyond the considerable loss of valuable signal from a trusted user, there is also a serious risk that [prolog] contributors will quit over this.

Comment: Yellow background instead of [red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/166789). You must be new here. At least it's freehand :-)

Comment: For a little more context here, this appears to have been part of a rage-quit on Stack Overflow and other sites. I had undeleted a large number of posts that they had deleted as part of trying to quit, and people let us know that they were acting weirdly and removing accounts on multiple sites. They had originally requested account deletion last week and had that declined, so I'm surprised to see this deletion actually go through. I thought it had been blocked.

Comment: @BradLarson: "They had originally requested account deletion last week and had that declined"  What?  I feel like something is amiss in your summary.  An account is maintained by mutual agreement of SO and the owner, according to the FAQ the account *will* be removed when the owner so requests.  I can understand not acting on a request suspected of being fraudulent, or doing a soft delete to give a chance to reconsider, but "declined"?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The top 5th Java user has about 40x higher tag upvotes (35.1k) than the top 5th Prolog's (890), so the relative impact of losing 70 votes is 40x smaller in Java. IOW, it's losing about 8% of your votes, vs. losing 0.2%. I think the latter has a much much smaller impact than the former.

Comment: @BenVoigt: there is no 'soft delete' option.

Comment: @WillNess: again, I strongly doubt that any such calculations are made. The total vote count is what matters here, not relative counts. The vast majority of users are not the top scorer in a tag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand that this is how the things stand *now*. I'm saying, it doesn't feel right. maybe the *relative* impact of votes removal should be considered instead of the absolute one -- for any user affected, consider the *percentage* of votes loss on each tag instead of the total number, then take an average. Maybe. Just a thought.

Comment: @WillNess: again, I think you are misunderstanding me. The impact on tags is not considered at all, nor should it. All I can say is that there is a process in place to retain user votes when the account is deleted when they have made a certain impact (have been around long enough, have cast enough votes, account has not been used to defraud). It looks like this account would have qualified. I asked the CM that handled this, they have not yet responded. That's about all that can be said here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you, I understood. I was just proposing maybe a change in the criteria. Just a vague thought. --- Hopefully they'll reconsider. Too bad about the whole situation, I had no idea that user felt this way. :(  (what is "CM"?)

Comment: @WillNess CM is a Community Manager, who is an actual Stack Exchange employee with special company powers to manage things that even elected moderators can't do.  This includes querying special databases (such as de-anonymized voting tables to investigate voting fraud).  They also handle account removals.

Comment: Why not just keep all votes that aren't fraudulent? Seems pretty stupid to have to decide what votes to keep and what not.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski: It's only "serial" if it was done in rapid succession. Votes over time, especially if the users share the same tag, are perfectly natural and are not invalidated.

Comment: @developerwjk: Uh, not sure if you see the irony in your comment.

Comment: @GrantWinney the current theory is that the main account also had two fringe accounts which engaged in what was deemed to be "voter fraud" (cross-voting of some sort). The main user probably vehemently denied this, wasn't believed, and rage-quit. Consequently not only the votes from the two suspected misused fringe accounts were lost (which makes total sense whatever the circumstances) but also all the votes done by the main account. I could see the logic if the bounties they gave were retracted (self-boosted rep given away...) but not the votes. looks like the 2 accts were *really* small.

Comment: @GrantWinney on the merits of their answers, their contribution is deemed to be high-grade by the experts on the tag. Seems that user's voting was objective, too. E.g. my loss of rep is much smaller than for the experts there (10+40+150 vs 140+325+1200 as posted by user "false" below). -- (scratch the word "really" in the above comment). But only the mods know the real numbers...

Comment: for some reason I misread the answer by false. the lost votes mentioned in my above comment were 10+40+150 vs 0+140+1200.

Comment: @WillNess: Help yourself in [my rep tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false?tab=reputation), it's 20+140+1200 and -2! I see these delete users quite frequently, so maybe there is more (that is more deleted accounts related to this). Mostly it's students who do not want to get caught by their prof. Easy to see when several ask the same question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After all this time this still makes no sense to me. They wanted to rage-quit; it looks like you have rage-agreed to their request.

If they artificially inflated their vote count and then gave the fake votes away as bounties, why not just zero out all the bounties they have ever given to anyone.

If they upvoted others, so what? What's the harm? Having meager 100 rep (or is it 50?) is enough to practically unlimited upvoting, day after day, week after week. So what's the harm if a high-rep user does it?

You could sum up all the votes they got from the upper level users on the tag -- who *are* legit -- and see that it was most certainly above the minimum level of a 100 (or 50). How do I know? I have just upvoted their old answer (and that's why I'm posting this answer, too).

If they pressured you in removing their account, why not rename it to *userNNN*, replace the user's password so they can't log in, and run your queries and analyses at your leisure pace.

And if your system doesn not allow you to do this, maybe it should.

Answer (score 36):

Out of respect for this person's privacy, I won't go into detail on what happened in this specific case.

I describe the process we use for vote preservation on user deletion here: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted/268608#268608)

We're pretty conservative about preserving votes; we do it when the disruption clearly outweighs the potential danger, but there's a lot of potential for it to break in hard-to-fix ways, so if there's any reason to believe it *will* cause problems we simply don't do it. Best solution is always to *not rage-quit*; you can walk away from an account for years and it'll be preserved; deletion is destructive by design.

Comment: Is there any thought to adjusting the thresholds per tag based on the level of voting in a specific tag to prevent it from being very distruptive to a tag with a lot of questions, but not heavy voting?

Comment: Where would you draw a line on that, @psubsee2003? If I'm the only voter in a tag, is that "too (relatively) big to fail", or "inconsequential tag"?

Comment: I think I get the picture, but, whatever happened on the fringes (and sometimes *mistakes* happen unintentionally, too), the center was solid it seems, and isn't removing collective, what, 5K+ rep a bit *disruptive*, hence  a *problem* in itself? IOW maybe restoring the lost votes is less of a problem than removing them, in this case? But of course you (I mean the SO team collectively) will be the judge on that. :)

Comment: @Shog9 obviously you are using counts instead percentages for a good reason (which I agree with), but there is probably 2nd check that could be done with % of the users votes in the tag (high enough to be disruptive but small enough that it isn't just a couple of people voting in the entire tag), combined with a minimum amount of activity (# questions, # of active users, # of users with > x rep). It would require some analysis with data mere mortals don't have access too.  Given other priorities, I can see why it might be too much for for too little gain with as infrequently it happens

Comment: @Shog9 so, is there still a chance the CM will reconsider, or is this the final verdict? (or maybe you are the CM in question?) Martijn Pieters [did say](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350352/user-in-good-standing-removed-significant-reputation-loss-in-low-traffic-tag/350381#comment479955_350352) that it "looks like this account would have qualified" [for vote retention]...

Comment: @psubsee2003 the problem is that each question can have up to 5 tags. It may be not disruptive in c, but it's on my-little-pony-library which is a c library. Maybe something like tags with x amount of answers, but then [string][windows][etc] would qualify too... it's not easy.

Comment: The account is removed, @Will - I had to step out of a concert last night to delete it, as the owner was very insistent. With it goes most of the data I would need to ensure the integrity of the votes, so no I can't in good conscience revisit this for the same reasons I couldn't preserve the votes in the first place.

Comment: @Shog9 OK, thanks for your consideration.

Comment: @Shog9 BTW I've read the linked answer closely and I think I understand what happened. Like I said, fringes / center.........  Oh well.

Comment: Upon reading this and the linked question I understand what happened here, but I'm confused by the very last sentence in your answer - "best solution is to not rage-quit."  Huh?  The OP of this question didn't rage-quit, and has pretty much no control over if another user rage-quits or not, so how is "don't rage-quit" supposed to help?  I'm probably misunderstanding what you mean, thought I'd request some clarification.

Comment: We're talking about what looks like 500-2000+ reputation lost for a number of users. That seems like it should we **WAY** above any threshold for "meh, let's just delete the votes". Unless it *was* above the threshold, yet you still just did it because keeping a single soon-to-be-former user happy is more important to you than all the users who will negatively be affected by your actions. Unless there was actually voter fraud involved here, which would be the only way this would make sense to me. Or if there were someone e.g. unbannably defiling posts, which seems implausible.

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question, @Dukeling.

Comment: At some point, you're either voting because you care about having accurate, useful information on the 'Net or you aren't, @Ajean. Some folks seem to think that by tearing down the walls on their way out they're hurting the mods, or the company that run these sites... They're mostly just hurting the folks like themselves who care - or once cared - about a particular topic. Obviously, trying to get this message across to someone *in the process of rage-quitting* doesn't usually work, so I like to acclimate folks to the idea ahead of time.

Comment: @Shog9: So, "keeping a single soon-to-be-former user happy is more important to you than all the users who will negatively be affected by your actions", then? Or what? Which of those three seemingly implausible possibilities is the right one?

Comment: @Shog9 Ok I see where you're going with that - maybe rephrasing that sentence might be cleaner though. "We really encourage people not to rage-quit" or something like that would get the point across better, because "don't rage-quit" isn't the "solution" to this particular issue raised by this OP.

Comment: @Shog9: Why do you need to react that promptly? All of this seems to have happened within less than two weeks. And why can't a deleted account be first just suspended, at least for the first time? Both could help to reduce what you call rage quit.

Comment: @false maybe the crossvoting was an innocent mistake and accusations of improper behavior incensed the user so much that he threatened legal action or whatever, forcing them to act quickly. only those who know the actual figures (amount of self-votes) can be in the position to form an informed opinion here.

Comment: @WillNess: I still fail to fathom the legal difference between a suspended and a deleted account. Both leave traces.

Comment: @false not on the site though. only on internet archive. it seems the site actually purges all information they have on the user in their servers. they probably have lots of logs.

Comment: @WillNess: But not the answers and the id.

Comment: @false answers are just plain text. but all the logs that they surely must have, all this is probably purged. maybe. who knows. the CM here seems to indicate this (like, logs of whom they voted for when, etc.).

Comment: @WillNess:  Highly unlikely, for they have to hand out information at the request of authorities.

Comment: @false BTW we know *one* figure of supposed alleged self-voting (out of supposed alleged two instances): you posted it: 325 rep on May 30th. Seems a whole lot of nothing for a user of 10k+ rep...

Comment: Let's drop the conspiracy theories; I've tried hard not to be too specific here because I see no reason to discuss someone's actions when they're not around to defend themselves. We try hard to honor deletion requests in a timely manner; I don't care much for sites that hold your account "hostage" when you want to leave. We only took as long as we did with this deletion to give the author a chance to cool down and think it over a bit, and to give me time to ensure the voting was analyzed properly; once done, there's no value in sitting on a request.

Comment: @WillNess: Maybe or not. After -325 was a serial compensatory upvoting (from probably the same account, same time, no double upvotes). And even that could have been the little brother/college roommate ... At least that came from a person not knowing  the notion of serial voting.

Comment: @Shog9 all right, but for us the prolog regulars, who saw the real value of that user's contributions through the years, the dismissal of all of their votes seems... it doesn't make much sense, really. deletion or not, the issue is vote retention from a valued contributor - valued, judging on merits of their answers.

Comment: @Shog9 as I said, we don't know the real voting data, so will have to live with your judgment on it.

Comment: @Shog9 Also this account https://stackoverflow.com/users/22676/per-mildner have gotten about 2700 rep from multiple bounties placed by  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false on the same answer.

Comment: @mega6382 so?  what are you implying?  I myself certainly upvoted many of user false's answers. so what? is an expert in the field not allowed to express their appreciation for an answer that "blows their mind"?

Comment: @WillNess I am not implying anything. You may very well be correct, I was just looking into the details of this question and ended up on that user's profile and it just seemed a bit suspicious to me. So, I posted a comment, as to someone(a mod) should look into it, nothing more.

Comment: @mega6382 the question is about another user that quit few months back. user false do what they please with their hard earned rep. which happens to be, to reward others participation in a low traffic tag that they seem to care about a lot. I have no personal knowledge otherwise.

Answer (score 33):

For the record, it seems that the regrettable deletion of user Boris/XXX/user1812457 was in itself <s>caused</s> influenced by another user deletion.  In fact,

1. On May 27 at 5:39 everything seemed to  be fine as exemplified by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328433/definition-of-a-path-trail-walk#comment75438574_30328433).
2. On May 30, I noted myself -140 due to a user deletion.
3. Around this time user Boris suffered -325 due to a user deletion.
4. The next I see is the name change to XXX. And the request to be deleted stated in the profile.
5. I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328433/definition-of-a-path-trail-walk#comment75774076_30328433) precisely about this this. And got a more or less confirming answer.
6. Today I see -1198. Now, at least I know where that one (1) dv came from 8-(.

Instead of [ridiculing constitutional amendments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/01/podcast-107-just-trying-non-terrible/), it might be more appropriate to consider **fundamental unalienable rights** for SO.

Comment: *"this was not the reason, just a symptom"* is "a more or less confirming answer"?

Comment: @PaulRoub: A denying answer sounds very different.

Comment: *one* dv, *ever*? :) -- silver linings...

Comment: @WillNess: That one dv ever by Boris.

Comment: @YowE3K: It says +2 / -1200  for me. So that is one dv less. And 120 upvotes less. Right?

Comment: Yep - that will have to be right. (I thought it might have just shown a net -1198, which could have been +12 / -1210.  You can tell I've never been affected by a deleted user event.)

Comment: have you also noticed your "user removed" rep changes on May 30th and 26th when you lost 12 and 2 upvotes respectively? these _might_ be related.

Comment: @WillNess: [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false?tab=reputation), could have escalated with serial compensatory upvotes which then count as fraud etc. Well, it's not easy here for a <10k language, but better than anywhere else: tag-edits, style attacks, deleted questions etc. One needs to deflect this one by one.

Comment: IOW, those two accounts could have been found to belong to the same actual person as the main one (which in itself is acceptable, iff there's no self-voting i.e. the dreaded "voter fraud"), and it might have been the case that there indeed was some cross-voting between these accounts, which could have prompted accusations of sockpuppetry. But it could've also been an honest mistake.

Comment: in any case, the votes by the "main" user were to the point, objective, judging by amounts you lost, and comparatively, how much smaller was my loss (which makes total sense).

Comment: @WillNess: Regardless on what happened on this level, the actual merits of Boris have not been taken into account. Or so it looks to me.

Comment: yes. though if there were some cross-voting, this is seriously frowned upon activity. but the main account indeed is solid. it makes perfect sense for the two accounts' votes to be retracted, but much less so for the main one. I could understand if any bounties given by them were retracted, but not the votes.

Comment: the "actual merits" that could have been known only by persons actually involved in the tag.

Comment: (one correction: "found to belong to same actual person" could only be a *suspicion* on SO's part - same IP number etc. it is actually possible for a PC to be actually shared by several people, though this "defense" is always going to be dismissed as spurious).