# -2 because of "user was removed"

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-users

I got -2 on the name of "user was removed" but I do not understand from where this -2 comes because, from my understanding, if a user is removed then I will get:

- -5 if they upvoted on my question
- -10 if they upvoted on my answer
- +2 if they downvoted me

What is the emanation of this -2 then?

Comment: Uber-Meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/175248

Comment: Remember that this goes both ways.  If you would've *gained* reputation from one of their actions, it would be reversed.  You likely accepted an answer of theirs, and their account was then destroyed.

Comment: it affects even an accepted answer of theirs? that is new to me. Thanks for the info @Makoto

Comment: If all you got was a -2 [consider yourself lucky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350352/user-in-good-standing-removed-significant-reputation-loss-in-low-traffic-tag)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could have:

- suggested an edit to a post of theirs that was deleted as a result of their deletion,
- been upvoted by them when you had earned 198 reputation from upvotes previously in that day,
- downvoted two of their answers that were deleted as a result of their account being deleted,
- been upvoted by them once, and downvoted by them 4 times,
- or any other combination of events that has a net change of 2, rather than being a single action.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ The deletion of a user can result in posts being deleted.  That you've never seen a low quality post here is, frankly, *astounding*.  You must be the single luckiest person in the entire world if you've been able to interact with thousands (if not tens of thousands) of posts and not once come across a single bad post.  You should buy some lottery tickets.

Comment: The point to downvoting is to point out that the post is bad, you can always take back your downvote if the post is improved later.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ If you're opposed to providing feedback on the quality of a post, then why upvote posts?  Why refuse to give others, and the system the useful information as to the fact that a post is of low quality, when you feel that a post is of low quality?  The system is dependant, in numerous ways, on people providing correct feedback on posts, and they cease to work when people refuse to provide said feedback.

Comment: "If you're opposed to providing feedback on the quality of a post": editing, commenting, flagging and voting to close provide also a form feedback on posts.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Editing is a way to improve a post, not provide feedback on it's quality.  Commenting is a way to describe how a post can be improved, not to provide feedback on it's quality.  Flagging is a way of indicating that a post requires moderator attention (usually because it should be deleted), not a way of providing feedback on its quality.  Closing is a way of saying the question cannot be answered on the site (which correlates strongly with being of low quality) but is not strictly a way of providing feedback on a post's quality.  Voting is how you provide feedback on quality.

Comment: "you could have downvoted two of their answers" That would be +2 rep.