# What is meant by 'high reputation user' on the 'User was removed' page?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-users

The second paragraph of [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) states:

> This removal occurs whenever a user is deleted, unless that user had a very **high reputation** score. Because **high-reputation** users have usually cast a great many votes, removing all of them could be that much more disruptive to other users. In such cases, the staff use a special deletion that preserves the votes, resulting in no reputation change for those who had been voted on by that user.

What is meant by **high reputation** in this context? Is it a user with `10k+` or `100k+`? Wouldn't it make more sense to protect the votes of those owning the [`Electorate`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badge or any specific number of votes instead?

Comment: I think this is done on a case-by-case basis, so there might not be a hard cutoff.

Comment: As noted, it doesn't have much to do with high reputation, more with the way he used his votes.  There is a human factor involved with this, an SO employee that needs to deal with a gross mishap.  Tends to involve a frequent contributor whose got his glass of discontent filled beyond the brim and wants to kill his account permanently.  Last time I saw it go wrong was with a [prolog] contributor that had enough.  Caught the employee at the wrong time, several tag contributors lost thousands of rep.  That can kill a tag community.

Comment: Related: [Is user's reputation one of criteria for keeping their votes after account deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302632)

Comment: Also to answer the "what is high rep..." part: [it is apparently about 1k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304111/297125) but again not the only consideration.

Comment: @HansPassant [yep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350352/user-in-good-standing-removed-significant-reputation-loss-in-low-traffic-tag).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically, an account removal will result in a small amount of reputation being lost distributed across multiple users on the site, so the removal is not significantly felt.

If a user has cast a lot of votes on content - namely, has upvoted a large number of posts, and/or has provided bounties to answers - then removing those votes becomes incredibly disruptive and would mean that a large number of users would lose significant reputation due to the account being removed.

Remember:  rep removal resulting from a user being removed indicates that **those votes should not have been cast in the first place**, which can imply that the account was illegitimately voting for content.  A high rep user typically *does not* illegitimately vote for content, so invalidating those votes based on that premise shouldn't apply.

High rep doesn't really have to factor into this, but for every high profile account deletion in which manual intervention was required, it was *usually* a user with a very large amount of reputation *and* votes.

Comment: I've heard of a high rep user who gave thousands of downvotes but only ever gave one upvote. Deleting him (hypothetically) would cause rep gain for many/most people, not loss. Would that count as disruptive? Would staff protect the downvotes?

Comment: @Cœur wouldn't the same argument apply?  High-rep means the downvotes were probably legit.

Comment: It seems like the only reason to remove votes on user deletion is that a user has voted illegitimately. And as this being the default behavior, that there is an assumption that the amount of user deletions due to illegitimate voting are much bigger than the deletion of valid users to validate that default behavior. I also think that nobody explicitly wants to remove valid votes on user deletion. I wonder if the system could be made even more precise by having an algorithm evaluating voting patterns of users, tagging them as legitimate users and automatically keep their votes on user deletion.

Comment: I think this could save some manual work for the admins as well.

Comment: @Alex:  It's already a manual, employees-only process when a user whose votes have wide-reaching consequences.  I see no reason to automate something which happens so sparingly.

Comment: If this is correct, the page should probably be reworded.